# issue accessing instance variable via included module's method

Tags: ruby, module, instance-variables, memoization

The example code and output can be found here:

```
module A
  def self.included(base)
    base.include InMethods
  end

  module InMethods
    def mem
      @mem ||= []
    end

    def add(n)
      mem += n
    end
  end
end

class Help
  include A
end

h = Help.new
h.add(1)
# in `add': undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Basically, I am included one module which includes a submodule, but the real problem is with the methods and the instance variable.  this is a common pattern for me, but since i am trying to do it from a module i've included, i'm having trouble.

Answer (score 2):

This actually has nothing to do with modules/inclusion/inheritance/whatever. You get the same error in a regular class.

```
class Help
  def mem
    @mem ||= 0
  end

  def add(n)
    mem += n
  end
end

Help.new.add(1)
# test.rb:16:in `add': undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

When you use the syntactic sugar `mem +=`, Ruby actually expands this into `mem = mem +`. The first problem is that this is interpreted left-to-right, so the `mem =` defines a local variable `mem` that masks your method. So then the second `mem` references a defined-but-unset local variable and you get `nil`.

The second problem is that you didn't define a setter `mem=` method, so it can't change `@mem` at all!

To fix both problems, you could do

```
attr_writer :mem

def add(n)
  self.mem += n
end
```

Comment: True, my wording is wrong. I meant "unset" for the second one. A weird artifact of how Ruby defines local variables.